# how to get radio back after installing new ROM

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, radio-firmware, fm-radio

After installing a new ROM (cm12.1) I have lost my radio app on my LG optimus G E975. What I have done to get it back..
1. I have taken backup of radio app  (on Android ver 4.4). But when I install on Lollipop version (cm 12.1) it says "app not installed".
2. I used Spirit FM also , but unfortunately quality is nowhere near to the original radio.

what should I do now... can anybody help me out please.

Comment: That's a bug actually. Custom roms doesn't seem to support Radio. Developers are still working on it.